# How to make warning functionality in Airflow for long running task properly?

Tags: python, google-cloud-composer, airflow

We want to create a warning functionality in Airflow (Google's Data Composer) similarly to timeout, but with some extra conditions:

- if "timeout" happens the long running task should not be failed or skipped, it MUST finish
- we want to send an email or log the timeout event after reaching the time limit without interrupting our long running task

For this I'm using a PythonOperator which tries to determine whether the long running task is still running or finished or timeout happened etc.

The problem is that I can't get information from the current Dag Run about the start time of the long running task while the status information of the same long running task is present.

In the example below the `checker` task tried to query the `status` and `start time` information.
The start time here has always None value. The branch operator decides if the warning mail is needed, and makes the branching accordingly. It read the XCOM, where it can find the output of the checker task. The merge task joins the branches and leads the execution into the end task.

```
def checker(ti, **kwargs):

    elapsed = None
    timeout = 120
    sleeptime = 10
    dag_instance = kwargs['dag']
    execution_date = kwargs['execution_date']
    monitored_task = dag_instance.get_task("long_process")

    while True:

        print("Checker:", str(elapsed))
        monitored_task_instance = TaskInstance(monitored_task, execution_date)

        monitored_task_status = monitored_task_instance.current_state()[0]
        print("task_status", monitored_task_status)

        monitored_task_instance_start_time = datetime.strptime(monitored_task_instance.start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
        elapsed = datetime.now() - monitored_task_instance_start_time

        if monitored_task_status == 'success' and elapsed < timedelta(timeout) :
            ti.xcom_push(key="checker_result", value="finished")
            print("checker: finished", str(elapsed))
            return
        
        if monitored_task_status == 'running' and elapsed >= timedelta(timeout):
            ti.xcom_push(key="checker_result", value="timeout")
            print("checker: timeout", str(elapsed))
            return

        time.sleep(sleeptime)
```

The below code here might not work properly in `checker` task (it was not tested, please consider it as pseudocode):

```
monitored_task_instance_start_time = datetime.strptime(monitored_task_instance.start_date, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
```

The branch reads the output of the checker task via XCOM and decides to select the warning mail branch or not.

```
def branch(**kwargs):
    ti = kwargs['ti']
    status = ti.xcom_pull(key="checker_result", task_ids=["checker"])[0]
    if status == "timeout":
        print("branch timeout")
        return "mail_sender"
    if status == "finished":
        print("branch finished")
        return "merge"
    print("branch", status)
```

**Questions:**

- How to do this warning functionality properly?
- How to get the start time for a task in the current Dag Run properly?

The rest of the code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta, date
import time
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.dummy_operator import DummyOperator
from airflow.operators.python_operator import BranchPythonOperator
from airflow.utils.trigger_rule import TriggerRule
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from airflow.models import TaskInstance
from airflow.utils.helpers import parse_template_string


yesterday = datetime.combine(datetime.today() - timedelta(1), datetime.min.time())
default_dag_args = {
    'start_date': yesterday,
    'email_on_failure': False,
    'email_on_retry': False,
    'retries': 0,
    'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
    'catchup': False
}

def long_process():
    print("long_process start:", str(datetime.now()))
    time.sleep(60)
    print("long_process done:", str(datetime.now()))

def mail_sender():
    print("mail_sender: mail sent.")

with DAG(
        dag_id='warning_mailer',
        default_args=default_dag_args,
        tags=['blablabla'],
) as dag:
    start = DummyOperator(task_id='start')
    end = DummyOperator(task_id='end', trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS)
    task_long_process = PythonOperator(
        task_id="long_process",
        python_callable=long_process
    )
    task_checker = PythonOperator(
        task_id="checker",
        python_callable=checker,
        provide_context=True
    )
    task_mail_sender = PythonOperator(
        task_id="mail_sender",
        python_callable=mail_sender
    )
    task_branch = BranchPythonOperator(
        task_id='branch',
        python_callable=branch,
        provide_context=True
    )
    task_merge = DummyOperator(
        task_id='merge',
        trigger_rule=TriggerRule.ALL_SUCCESS
    )

    start >> [task_long_process, task_checker]
    task_long_process >> end
    task_checker >> task_branch >> [task_merge, task_mail_sender]
    task_mail_sender >> task_merge >> end
```

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for SLA ? https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/concepts.html#slas